# Nested calling of methods annotated with @Transactional and timeout propagation

Tags: timeout, spring-transactions

I wasn't able to find out what is the behaviour of transactional system when calling method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout=2)` within the method, which is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, timeout=10)`.

What is the resulting timout for inner transaction and why?

We use Spring 3.0 and hibernate 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout in the nested method (2) is ignored, since it will join the same transaction. There is no "inner transaction".